# What's an easy way to do a DDoS experiment without breaking any big rules?

Tags: networking, ddos

I thought of buying my own website www.zzzwew.com and doing a DDoS on it, but it looks like that won't work...

So if I get a goDaddy page and try to DDoS it that would hurt GoDaddy's general service?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to do that only when all the hardware involved is yours: your client computers, your server, your network routers, cables, etc. In all other cases it constitutes a crime in most countries. It's not worth to go to jail for such nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

GoDaddy will get really pissed, and possibly press legal charges if is a large enough scale (DISCLAIMER: Stack Overflow is a terrible place for legal advice). Mainly because even if all you are doing is attacking a server you own, you are also seriously stressing their network and equipment getting all that traffic to the server, which may affect other customers as well.

You're best bet is to do this completely isolated on your own hardware using a local network and make sure all traffic goes through equipment you own.

Comment: Not much of an option for DDoS (the very point being that first D, for "distributed").  It's pretty much a thing that's only truly doable on internet scale -- and that's going to involve someone else's hardware unless you own your own ISP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice!  I will get an old PC and set up a home website then. I hope I can revive my old HP that died though, else I'll buy an E-machine.

Comment: @adelCS: Make sure your ISP won't mind the extra traffic.  They can get kinda pissy about attacks (simulated or not) as well, especially when you're the one orchestrating them.

Comment: Yes you're right about the ISP issue. I will find out and I will choose a really off-peak time (4am - 7 am ).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a general observation: Probably not the best idea to sign up for a site and have your very first post be to ask how to conduct a Denial of Service attack.

You haven't said **why** you want to do this, so I suspect many people here will be leery of answering your question. Having spent a number of years in the computer security field, I can tell you that the world doesn't need any more hackers. There **are** some legitimate reasons for learning to to perform Denial of Service attacks (such as protecting yourself from them), but I'd suspect that anyone actually needing to do such a thing for legit reasons would already own a site and know the ramifications of a DDoS.

The short answer to your question, though, is this: were you to buy a GoDaddy account for the purpose of conducting DDoS experiments, you might want to hire a good lawyer first. GoDaddy's a big company with a lot of resources, and I suspect they take DDoS attacks on their shared servers **very** seriously.

I don't mean to sound flippant with my answer, especially if the motive for your question is legit, but if you really need to do tests like these, you need to do it on an inhouse server.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would get a box and set it up on your own network. Getting a Godaddy account and dosing it can hurt other people that share it with you. Furthemore, in some areas, it is illegal to own DoS software. Check for your area.

Why do you need to test this? To learn how to mitigate it. Lots of people have done it and you can just follow their work.

My advise however, if you really want to learn how to DoS is to get a box. A simple desktop for 199 will work. Put some linux OS on it with apache. 
Put up a simple page. and google around for some tools. LoIC is what Anonymous used during an attack on master card and paypal. Most of them ended up in jail. 
Things to watch out for:

Make sure that the computer your attacking with and to are not on the net. Use a switch to connect the two machines -- just so you don't accidentally take someone else down. 
This will also provide you the best case scenario. Omega. You will have the highest bandwidth to the target. Bandwidth is what you really need for most DoS attacks.